Ubuntu 24.04 LTS 4070 Super not outputting to display from Graphics Card HDMI Port
I have system with NVIDIA 4070 Super (ASUS TUF GAMING OC) and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. The system is not outputting to display from the graphics card.
Fortunately, the AMD on-board GPU is providing output through the motherboard.
Steps I've Tried:
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Removed the auto installed drivers here is the list that i have tried 525 535 550 555.52.04
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525 nvidia-dkms-525

Tried Blacklisting the Simpledrm drivers using the GRUB it also dint work.
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
add "initcall_blacklist=simpledrm_platform_driver_init" to where it says GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash", so it looks like this:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash initcall_blacklist=simpledrm_platform_driver_init”

None of these versions provided output through the HDMI port.
lspci Output.
❯  lspci | grep -e VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation AD104 [GeForce RTX 4070 SUPER] (rev a1)
0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raphael (rev cb)

System Info
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 6.8.0-35-generic 
Uptime: 9 mins 
Packages: 1686 (dpkg), 75 (nix-user), 10 (snap) 
Shell: zsh 5.9 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 46.0 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D (16) @ 5.050GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI 0c:00.0 Raphael 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 SUPER 
Memory: 2594MiB / 31296MiB 

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Why is this a down vote what is the issue in the above question. ?
